# Transfer a TeleDisk image of a 5.25 disk to a 3.5 disk

Tags: floppy-disk, disk-image

I am trying to power on an old **Siemens PG675**. It need a 5.25 disk but unfortunately it is missing. I found a TeleDisk image (.TD0) of this disk, and I would like to transfer it to a 3.5 floppy disk (I replaced the original 5.25 reader with a dual 5.25 and 3.5 unit from a PG750-486).

I have used dsktools, but it gives me this error when I try the "Copy" option:
"Error on file A::  Bad format".

Comment: Is the floppy disk blank? Is it new? Is it error-free? Is it formatted? Have you tried with multiple floppy disks?

Comment: I have tried with 720 KB and 1.4MB. After several test I think I have found a way to do it.
**1.)** I use a 1.44 MB floppy and put some tape on the second hole (the one that is not used to avoid the writing) 
**2.)** With the Windos CMD I use this command: `format a:/f:720`
**3.)** I get a copy of TeleDisk and run it on a __Win XP__ machine.

**4.)** I inserted this floppy in the PG and it seems to be correctly read

Comment: Was it <https://www.seasip.info/Unix/LibDsk/>? It would have helped if the asker mentioned the options used. The command-line `dsktrans` offers a `-format` option, which I would have tried first at least.